# Vuejs: Re-Render List

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to figure out how to re-render a list of name types. I want to ensure that only one name with type 0 (primary) exists at a time, so I want to enable/disable that option based on the number of names in my array with type 0.

```
<a v-for="type in names.types" v-bind:class="[canAddNameType(type) ? '' : 'disabled', 'dropdown-item']" href="#">
    @{{ type.type }}
</a>
```

How can I make my list get re-rendered every time I add/remove a name?

Comment: Depending on how you add/remove, it should happen automatically.

Comment: This does depend on how you add or remove elements; given that you're working with an array I suspect you'll need to use `$set` when modifying `names`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set

Comment: @BertEvans I am not adding/removing types from the names.types array, I am adding/removing names from the names array.  I agree that it should happen automatically if I am adding/removing types from the types list.

Comment: Make a computed that renders the current list of types based on the names.

Answer (score 0):

Work directly with the nested data and bind to the `key` property for each item:

**Template**

```
<a v-for="type in types" 
   :key="type.type"
   :class="[canAddNameType(type) ? '' : 'disabled', 'dropdown-item']" href="#">
    @{{ type.type }}
</a>
```

**Script**

```
computed: {
    types() {
        return this.names.types
    }
}
```